# Debian cron.daily messages

Tags: linux, cron

Every week, I seem to be getting the following two Cron messages:
`/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:`
`gzip: stdin: file size changed while zipping`

`/etc/cron.daily/spamassassin:`
`channel: no 'mirrors.updates.spamassassin.org' record found, channel failed`
`sa-update failed for unknown reasons`

Not sure what's causing these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what the messages say.

In the first case something was writing to the file being archived while the archiving was taking place.

In the second case, Spam Assassin was unable to access the mirror it needed to update itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't made any custom changes to the cron.daily directory or logrotate. So, would this be a bug in Debian?

Comment: Not sure if you would class it as a bug in Debian (don't want to go there anyway, but see http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/07/msg01955.html).  You can "work around this issue by modifying the scripts in /etc/logrotate.d and removing the "compress", or possibly by adding the "delaycompress" option.

Comment: To look at the spamassassin problem can you provide the output of sa-update and also what happens if you ping mirrors.updates.spamassassin.org

Comment: sa-update does not give me any messages. The ping fails with an 'unknown host' message.

Comment: I'll add 'delaycompress' and let you know if it helps.

Comment: Well I don't seem to be getting those messages anymore. Seems like 'delaycompress' worked.

Comment: Which daemon's logrotate file did you add delaycompress to?

Answer (score 11):

Adding `delaycompress` in relevant log rotation configuration files may help with the first error.

This can be done as default here `/etc/logrotate.conf` or more specifically in any of the package specific configuration files in `/etc/logrotate.d`.

About `delaycompress` (emphasis added):

> Postpone compression of the previous log file to the next rotation cycle. **This only has effect when used in combination with compress**. It can be used when some program cannot be told to close its logfile and thus might continue writing to the previous log file for some time.

so if you add it in the global config file you need to add `compress` too, which you might not want to do.

Alternatively, you need to track down which package is problematic - not easy but here are some hints:

- Discover which config files have the `compress` option on: `cd /etc/logrotate.d` and then `grep "compress" *`
- Of these, find out which ones *don't* also have `delaycompress`
- Compare with the last rotated time in `/var/lib/logrotate/status` and the size of the log file, and with a bit of inference & hand waving you might have narrowed it down sufficiently
- Then add `delaycompress` to the relevant config file e.g. `/etc/logrotate.d/PACKAGENAME`

Comment: Thanks. You may also change `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf` into `/usr/sbin/logrotate --verbose /etc/logrotate.conf` in `/etc/cron.daily/` to find out which logfile is problematic.

Comment: Hint: from various posts on the web, samba seems to be problematic [at least in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=702201).

Comment: I really liked the suggestion of adding the verbose to debug! Ironically, after doing that I cannot see the same error message that was appearing before anywhere in the debug message...